# SQL Syntax error near 'nvarchar' in my python script when trying to import excel file to dataframe

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

Currently have a SQl DOcker image that contains my SQL Server DB and I'm currently connecting to it by running a python script that will source my excel file and convert it to a dataframe which in turn will be turned into a table for my DB. Right now I keep getting this error  `pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'nvarchar'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")`  and my python code is here:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

# Import CSV
data = pd.read_excel (r"C:\Users\c.stembridge\OneDrive - NEWREST GROUP SERVICES\Overtime Forecast Report.xlsx", sheet_name='Daily Hrs2')   
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Connect to SQL Server
conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;UID=SA;PWD=Working@2022;DATABASE=testdb;Encrypt=no;TrustServerCertificate=yes")
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Create Table
cursor.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE Overtime_Forecast (
            date nvarchar(10) primary key,
            day nvarchar(9),
            hrs int,
            dl int,
            catered int,
            hrs_diff_btwn_last_day int,
            catered_flight_diff int,
            employees_OT_count int,
            carriers int,
            whole int,
            half int,
            total_carts int
            )
               ''')

# Insert DataFrame to Table
for row in df.itertuples():
    cursor.execute('''
                INSERT INTO Overtime_Forecast (
                        date nvarchar(10) primary key,
            day nvarchar(9),
            hrs int,
            dl int,
            catered int,
            hrs_diff_btwn_last_day int,
            catered_flight_diff int,
            employees_OT_count int,
            carriers int,
            whole int,
            half int,
            total_carts int)
                VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
                ''',
                row.Date,
                row.Day,
                row.Hrs,
                row.DL,
                row.Catered,
                row.Hrs_diff_btwn_last_day,
                row.Catered_flight_diff,
                row.Employees_OT_count,
                row.Carriers,
                row.Whole,
                row.Half,
                row.Total_carts
                )
conn.commit()
```

Comment: Why are you declaring types in your INSERT?

Comment: Why shouldn't I declare types using insert? @JacobIRR

Comment: Because the datatype is declared on the table. It is invalid syntax to specify the datatype in an insert.

Comment: The table knows its own types since you CREATEd it.

Comment: Notice that datatypes aren't defined as part of the syntax in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) either. Don't *assume* syntax, if you don't know what it is look it up.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the types from your INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO Overtime_Forecast (
                        date,
            day,
            hrs,
            dl,
            catered,
            hrs_diff_btwn_last_day,
            catered_flight_diff,
            employees_OT_count,
            carriers,
            whole,
            half,
            total_carts ...
```